# Lock Oracle row so second thread cannot read data

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle

How do I block one thread's transaction from reading a row until another transaction has finished processing it?

I have a trigger table on an Oracle 11 DB. A row on the trigger table has a status flag to indicate whether a process needs to happen or not - let's say it's to trigger an email. there is abatch process regularly polling the trigger table. The process is:

1. get X number of triggers where status is NOT_SENT
2. update status of X triggers to SENDING
3. send X emails
4. update status of X triggers to SENT

But I am running my application in a clustered environment. So there could be multiple versions of the batch process pulling down triggers in parallel. I want to ensure that the competing batch processes do not pull down the same triggers and perform the same processing i.e. send the same email.

I am looking at the Oracle SELECT FOR UPDATE clause. However, I'm not 100% clear if this does what I want. I need thread A to lock the trigger row and thread B to be blocked from reading from or writing to the trigger row. It is not 100% clear if SELECT FOR UPDATE blocks thread B from reading and writing OR blocks thread B from writing only. I need the former.

Thoughts welcome.

Comment: You can not do that generally. In Oracle reading can never be blocked. You can block only someone who has contract with you. i.e. the other thread has to try to lock the same lock as you hold.

It does not matter whether you both execute `select .. for update` or you use dbms_lock.

Comment: In general, **Readers do not block writers and writers do not block readers**.

Comment: @ibre5041 this contradicts the answer from Justin Cave below. He says SELECT FOR UPDATE locks first then reads. I will test to confirm.

Comment: @CodeClimber - Pure readers never block.  You can't stop a pure `SELECT`.  A `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is not a reader in a strict sense-- it has to acquire a lock before it can start reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `SELECT FOR UPDATE` locks and reads the row.  If thread A has locked the row and thread B tries to lock it, thread B will block until thread A releases its lock.  So if both A and B are doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, thread B will wait until A is done.

In Oracle, a reader is never blocked by a writer so other threads will be free to read the rows that A is processing.  They just won't be able to lock the rows.

Of course, it rather defeats the purpose of have multiple threads if your locking mechanism turns your application into something that is functionally single threaded.  You may want to look into doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`.  Here is a nice illustration of [how `SKIP LOCKED` works](https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/select_for_update_nowait_skip).

Comment: Leaving SKIP LOCKED aside for a moment, if I use SELECT FOR UPDATE, then thread B will be able to read the pre-update value of the row even if it is locked by thread A (which is what I don't want). Correct?

Comment: @CodeClimber - If both A and B are doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, the order of operations is lock then read.  If A has locked the row, B's attempt to lock the row via `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will block until A is done.  B won't be able to move on to reading the row until after it is able to lock it.  Other sessions doing a plain `SELECT` rather than a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will always be able to read the rows.

Comment: Got it now, thanks. I take your point above about this becoming a pseudo-single-threaded solution. I disagree slightly as it is only the reading and updating of the trigger flag that will block. The actual processing of the trigger (sending the mails in my example above) will be run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL block (a trigger is also PL/SQL block) you can use [dbms_lock](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm) package.