# Oracle and Java : How to avoid two different threads read the same rows from table contains million records

Tags: java, oracle

How to avoid two different java threads read the same rows from table contains million records.

I have to process million records and there wont be any where clause in the query (as need to process all the available records)

How can i do it ? Not using any java framework

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400217/266304) may be relevant - using `select for update ... skip locked`?

Comment: @AlexPoole – I just know how to spell the name of the RDBMS product correctly ("Orakel", right?), so please excuse me if I am wrong here. But my understanding is that a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause would lock the whole table at once. If so, one thread would process all records, and the other threads will not see even one – until the lock is released and they will see them all (or is the latter scenario prevented by the `… SKIP LOCKED` clause you mentioned?).

Comment: @tquadrat - if one thread locked all rows then the second would skip them all and do nothing; but I don't think that's what would happen. The table wouldn't be locked, rows would be locked as they are fetched, so each thread would lock `fetchsize` rows at a time, which could be interleaved. I believe... However, without a `where` or perhaps more importantly an `order by`, there's nothing stopping one thread processing rows the other has read and then released (when it committed/rolled back/closed its connection).

Comment: Processing millions of rows without a mechanism taking note of what has been processed is a potential open door to data corruption, ... think about software bug, hardware failure, network down, out of DB tmp space ,.. during the processing forcing you to relaunch... how to handle correctly without a recording of what has already been processed?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

that is executed in a method `doProcess()`, running in several threads.

From all I know about RDBMS (and that is not that much), `SELECT` does not lock the records it reads. That means that all instances of `doProcess()` will get the same set of records and will process them – with the result, that each record is processed multiple times.

To get out of this, think about this structure (*THIS IS NOT JAVA CODE!*):

```
class Processor implements Runnable
{
  private final MyRecord m_Record;
  public Processor( final MyRecord record ) { m_Record = record; }
  final void run() { doProcess(); }
}

…
var resultSet = executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
while( resultSet.hasMoreEntries() )
{
    var record = resultSet.getEntry();
    var processor = new Processor( record );
    threadPool.execute( processor );
}
```

To implement this in *real* Java, have a look to `java.sql.ResultSet`, `Executors` and alike. You also need to create a `MyRecord` type that is initialised from the `ResultSet`.

Basically, you have one single thread that is reading the data from the database (and does nothing more!), then it pulls another thread from a thread pool that does the processing of a single record and triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the rows from one thread but pass each Row, as read from a ResultSet, to a pool of worker threads for faster processing.

Each row will be processed exactly once and you can configure your pool for maximum throughput.